# React Native IOS Ajax takes much longer than Android

Tags: ios, ajax, react-native, axios

React Native version 0.63

upload of ~2mb image takes 10s in android and more than minute in IOS
I am using axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. problem with react-native-amazing-cropper packg.
somehow it doubles image size after cropping (only in ios). and as result 2mb image will be 4mb in server